# SQL Trigger solve

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER Print
Before UPDATE ON employ
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.Employe_ID>0)
DECLARE
    salary int;
BEGIN
    salary:= :NEW.salary-:OLD.salary;
    dbms_output.put('Old salary:'||:OLD.salary);
    dbms_output.put('New salary:'||:NEW.salary);
    dbms_output.put_line('Difference'||salary);
END; 
/
```

Shows

> error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN (NEW.Employe_ID>0)
>   DECLARE
>       salary int' at line 4

I have a table name employe which has 4 columns Employe_ID, E_name,
Department_ID,
salary

What is the problem with this sql and how can I solve it?

Comment: your synyax suggests oracle,declarations are after BEGIN in mysql and you need a delimiter.Google a basic mysql trigger,it seems to me you copied a Oracle trigger and want the community to de the translation to mysql

Comment: How should we know how to solve it if you don't describe what you try to do?

Comment: sorry for the incomplete Qn without proper detail.I am trying to capture the change of a Salary in the employee table  and store the data in a Salary_ history table


and another thing i want to ask Which part has the oracle trigger that need to change into mysql ?

thank you again for you comment i am very much grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you added the condition `on employee_id > 0`, but in case you actually need it

```
delimiter //

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER print BEFORE UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW 
IF ( NEW.employe_id > 0 ) THEN
  SELECT NEW.salary - OLD.salary INTO @delta;
END IF;
//

delimiter ;
```

Insert and update your data, then read @delta

```
insert into employee select 1,'Me',1,2400;
update employee set salary = 2800 where id = 1;

Select @delta;
```

I don't think it's possible to automatically output @delta to the screen as it would be on Oracle using dbms_output.put_line().